# Angular Cli 6 how to use command parameters in proxy.conf.js

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular-cli-v6

I am using the new `angular.json` file of Angular Cli 6 and for my application I need to specify a `proxy.conf.js`. So for my application, I have to specify:

```
...
"appName": {
    ...
    "serve": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
      "options": {
        "browserTarget": "appName:build",
        "proxyConfig": "proxy.conf.js"
      }
    }
    ...
}
...
```

In my `proxy.conf.js`, I am mocking the connected user to the headers but I would like to be able to inject it dynamically by using the command line.

With Angular 5 I was doing:

```
yarn start appName --proxy-config proxy.conf.js --user=MyConnectedUser
```

And in the `proxy.conf.js` I just take the parameter `user` and I mock it in my headers

But with Angular Cli 6 it is not allowed to specify other options:

```
Unknown option: '--user'
```

Any advises how can I provide a user dynamically to my proxy-conf ?